# google cloud-storage for existing appengine accounts

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

i have existing appengine accounts that need to have cloud storage capability.

but it seems that i cant add it to an existing app engine account.

https://cloud.google.com/products/cloud-storage

instead i must create a new 'project' which creates a new appengine account.

is there a difference when having the cloud storage in a different 'project' beside having a different name?

thanks
-lp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the solution.

the appengine settings page has a button for enabling 'Cloud Integration'

Administration->application settings->cloud integration

click the button and an existing appengine project will become a cloud project and there is now a option in the cloud console to add the cloud storage.

Comment: I keep having the "An error ocurred when creating the project. Please retry." message.

Comment: (Can't edit the comment above). Refer to the [issue #9602](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9602).

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Storage documentation is quite explicit about enabling GCS for existing AppEngine projects:

[GCS Docs - enabling for old style AppEngine apps](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/activate#google_cloud_datastore_for_accessing_an_existing_app_engine_datastore_from_compute_engine)