# How to add Google Cloud Storage to existing project

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am trying to get my brain wrapped around Google Services. I have an existing Google App Engine running and would like to add Google Cloud Storage to the project?

Any help appreciated.

Regards

Comment: i had the same issue.
answer is here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332883/google-cloud-storage-for-existing-appengine-accounts

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following documentation and see if that helps:

[Activate Google Cloud Storage](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/signup)

Comment: The documentation doesn't cover how to activate the service for an **existing** App Engine project. All it says is what to do when you create a new project.